# Samsung GT-S 5300

Tags: sd-card

sd card:
 total space: unavailable
available space: unavailable
mount sd card: insert sd card- 
Format sd card:

my problem is that sd card is inside but it keeps telling me to insert it. How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well for the lack of information in your post, there could be many issues here. A damaged card or slot for one. An incompatible file system. Try formatting the card on your PC and re-inserting to see if it works. If not, it's time to get a new card.

If you card works on your PC and not on your phone, than it's a fault of the SD card slot of your phone.